# How do I specify my Topology class when submitting the jar via NimbusClient?

Tags: java, deployment, apache-storm

I am able to submit my jar via Nimbus client to a remote server where Nimbus is running.

I can see a topology entry on the storm ui as well however, I could not see the spout and bolt details on the next page. Also, none of the life cycle methods have been invoked.

I suspect the topology main method within the jar has not been invoked as I didn't specify the class name anywhere in the config.

This works if I deploy it directly via command line i.e ./storm jar #jar# #classname#.

If you notice the storm ui, the topology name is taken from the Nimbus client submitter not the name given in my topology class.

### My topology submitter code below

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
Map storm_conf = Utils.readStormConfig();
storm_conf.put("nimbus.host", "<hostname>");

String inputJar = "C:/Users/MY-TOPOLOGY-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar";
NimbusClient nimbus = new NimbusClient(storm_conf, "<hostname>",6627);
String uploadedJarLocation = StormSubmitter.submitJar(storm_conf,inputJar);

String jsonConf = JSONValue.toJSONString(storm_conf);
nimbus.getClient().submitTopology("central-cache",uploadedJarLocation, jsonConf, builder.createTopology());
System.out.println("Topology submitted");
```

### My topology class main method is below

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("spout1", new MySpout(), 3);
builder.setBolt("bolt1",new MyBoltOne(),3).setNumTasks(3).shuffleGrouping("spout1");
builder.setBolt("bolt2",new MyBoltTwo(),3).setNumTasks(3).shuffleGrouping("bolt1");

Config conf = new Config();
conf.setNumWorkers(3);
conf.setDebug(true);

StormSubmitter.submitTopology("central-cache-topology",conf,builder.createTopology());
```

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: <<author>>
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_45
Main-Class: com.gooe.ews.storm.CentralCacheTopology
```

Storm UI Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Without the invocation of the main method, the topology will not be visible on the storm ui. Since, your topology is visible, it means the main method is invoked. Sounds more like a storm ui issue. Could you share your code snippet or the ui screenshot for more help.

Comment: Hi Daniccan - thanks for your response. I have updated my post with Nimbus Client program /Topology class and other related info. Please help.